# Can I run Emacs M-x ediff on Windows without installing Cygwin?

Tags: windows, emacs, diff

Is it necessary to install Cygwin (which includes diff) or MinGW (which presumably also does) for something as simple as determining the differences between foobar.txt and foobar.txt~?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need those long as you have a diff.exe program, such as the GNUWin32 diff-utils version, in your PATH.  Emacs itself doesn't include the mechanics for performing the diffs.